# Increase VM RAM memory size

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have Ubuntu VM running on Windows 8 WMware host computer. I would like to increase it's memory size, but looks I have no more sliding bar available to do that. How to increase the memory size allocated to the VM?

[image]

I run Windows 8 64 bits on host computer with 24 Gb RAM and Ubuntu 64 bit VM

Comment: How much memory does the host computer have?

Comment: Also, is the VM powered on already?

Comment: You have either already allocated the most VMWare will allow you to allocate to the virtual because of the version you are using or it is because you have already allocated as much as VMWare is allowed to offer you to allocate.  This might because you allocated more then a 32-bit operating system can handle ( You indicated to VMWare what OS you would install when you created the virtual machine originally ) or more likely your actually running a 32-bit host operating system and that is the actual limit a process can be allocated (3GB) already unless you use `PAE`.

Comment: If you clarify your question I will reverse my vote because it currently is extremely difficult to know which one of the three different scenarios applicable.

Comment: I have described my situation more detail. And got solution.

Comment: It would be helpful to others with a similar problem if you post your solution as an answer.  You will also be able to accept it in two days, which will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Comment: Why so many downvoates?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is soved after I shudown system. I was trying to change RAM size on running one. And I don't know why it is possible only in up to 4Gb. When system is shut down I can change whatever I need.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of available memory depends on current hardware version of a virtual machine
Check this link to learn more
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014006

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.